# autoKey gtk 0.95.10 Icon get red an autoKey freezing

Tags: autohotkey, autokey

[autoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/API-Examples#clipboard) often stops working if i press my script shortcut <kbd>F12</kbd>

about every 70%. And about every 50% of them the icon gets red and autoKey is freezing. CPU load grows a little bit.

Its difficult to say what may the reason it.

The script ([gist](https://gist.github.com/3abb839ca3f7d76b784c93edcbc6fa49) is a bit large. 
 About 500 lines and offered on [github](https://github.com/sl5net/Lintalist4Linux).

I debug by sending while i recording my desktop to video file ([youtub LKl4Ufhh3P8](https://youtu.be/LKl4Ufhh3P8) ).

it open via [wine](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/01/install-wine-5-0-stable-ubuntu-18-04-19-10/) a menu ([autoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script called [lintalist](https://github.com/lintalist/)) and catches the changed clipboard and writes it out.

When I restart the autoKey script it runs a couple of times (maybe three or five times). I inserted 100 milliseconds as a pause at various points. Since then, I don't have to restart the operating system, only kill the script when it freezes.

any idea what to try?

#### for debugging i use such little helpers:

```
import subprocess
doPopupNotify_howItWorks_counter = 0
doPopupNotify_howItWorks_firstNr = 15
doPopupNotify_howItWorks = True

def popupNotify(text):
    subprocess.Popen(['notify-send', text])  # will be showed right top

def popupNotify_howItWorks(text):
    global doPopupNotify_howItWorks, doPopupNotify_howItWorks_counter
    if not doPopupNotify_howItWorks:
        return
    doPopupNotify_howItWorks_counter = doPopupNotify_howItWorks_counter + 1
    if doPopupNotify_howItWorks_counter < doPopupNotify_howItWorks_firstNr:
        return
    subprocess.Popen(['notify-send', str(doPopupNotify_howItWorks_counter) + ") " + text])  # will be showed right top
    time.sleep(.2)
```

#### System

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-52-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
autoKey gtk 0.95.10
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem was. but one of my changes (the last one) was the change from `autokey-gtk` to `autokey-qt`. It works in the first few tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These problems have not disappeared for a few days as a result of the following changes:

The solution described above uses the clipboard and keyboard together with Linux and Windows (Wine) conveyed via two scripting languages.

**Apps:**
clipboard ⇄ AutKey ⇄ AutoHotKey ⇄ Lintalist

**operating systems:**
clipboard ⇄ [Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org/) ⇄ [WineHQ](https://www.winehq.org/) <sup>1</sup>

Errors are more common in non-closed systems. Therefore, for example, such errors are typical (still open problem at 2020:11:12 in autokey):

["Hotkeys get lost when triggered frequently"](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/issues/403)

1. change from `autokey-gtk` to `autokey-qt` for systems using a Qt-based desktop environment such as KDE Plasma, Lumina, etc. For that there are different possibilities ([github: install using pip3](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/blob/master/INSTALL)). I've used  i used:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove autokey-gtk
sudo apt -y install autokey-qt
```

2. changed in AHK-Souce

```
ClipboardFirst := RTrim(LTrim(Clipboard, " `n`t:")," `n`t")
to
ClipboardFirst := RTrim(LTrim(Clipboard, " `n`t`r:")," `n`t`r")
```

The autokey icon still sometimes turns red, but the CPU load does not grow much and the system no longer freezes.

---

1: Wine is a free implementation of Windows on Linux.

[Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org/) Version 20.04

AutoKey Version 0.95.10

Python Version 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40)  [GCC 9.3.0]

wine-5.0.1